# TSQL: Function to display month in words not numbers

Tags: t-sql

```
MONTH(CMS.App_Received_Date) as 'App Month'
```

will return `4` for April when date is like `2012-04-01`

will return `5` for May   when date is like `2012-05-02` etc

Is there a TSQL function to return April, May, June instead?

i.e. `MONTHNAME(CMS.App_Received_Date) as 'App Month'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DATENAME(month, CMS.App_Received_Date) as 'App Month'
```

Comment: Lol. So there is something built in. Thanks. I was starting to write the case statement for it.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  DATENAME(month, '2012-04-01') AS 'App Month'
```

Returns a character string that represents the specified datepart of the specified date.

Note that the return value depends on the language environment, in my case it returns `Januar` (german).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx